# How to remove the .git folder through terminal in Linux (WSL)?

Tags: windows, git, terminal

I want to init a git repo in a folder, but a subfolder in that folder already has a git repo. How do I keep the parent git repo as the only one?

I tried to remove the .git folder in the subfolder through the file explorer in Windows (I'm using WSL), but I am getting this error :

[image: error]

Comment: You probably can’t remove it via Explorer (straightforwardly) because the objects in the database are write-protected.

Comment: did you try renaming the folder to .git_backup

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Hogan I didn't. But I simply used rm -rf .git . It worked.

Comment: Well, looks like you already figured it out?  I was wondering whether the inner folder might've been opened in Visual Studio.  I haven't used Windows in a long time, but vaguely remember that you might get that dialog in WSL if anything in Windows itself has a handle to the file - like a text editor or Git client.

Comment: In case you don't know, the .git folder contains your entire local repository. If you delete it you can never recover the changes it contained.  If you rename the folder it is easy to get those changes back.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks for pointing that out. I removed it because I had only 1 commit up until then. But I'll keep this in mind next time.